# Ошибка при подключении .css, .js к шаблону laravel 8

Tags: javascript, html, css, laravel

С этого сайта взяты "методы" как это сделать,
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28104583/how-to-include-external-css-and-js-file-in-laravel-5

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('css/test1.css') }}" /><!--Recommended-->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ URL::asset('css/test1.css') }}" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ URL::to('css/test1.css') }}" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url('css/test1.css') }}" />
```

но почему-то ни один из них не функционирует, а почему ?

полный путь к .css файлу => resources/css/test1.css

Comment: `asset('css/test1.css')` берет файл из `public/css/`, а не из `resources/css/`. Либо кладите общедоступные файлы в `public` (пойдёт только как временное решение), либо изучайте https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/mix

Answer (score 0):

Самый оптимальный вариант - это использование [Laravel Mix](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/mix).
С его помощью Вы сможете подключить CSS и JS следующим образом:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ mix('css/app.css') }}"></link>
<script src="{{ mix('js/app.js') }}"></script>
```

Comment: Выводит: The Mix manifest does not exist. (View:шаблон

Comment: mix-manifest.json появится, когда вы запустите npm run build (npm run dev) и не забудьте проверить сам webpack.mix.js, есть ли там нужные действия с файлами